# Screen Reader always "converts" the WPF Slider value to within 0-100 range

Tags: wpf, slider, screen-readers

For those who have experience working with screen readers (ex. JAWS), my question is on how to modify the WPF slider so that the value that the screen reader reads out is the same as what's in `Slider.Value`?

JAWS always reads the value of the slider as something between the 0-100 range. I don't know how it gets this value. It's probably from computing the location of the Slider.Value between the `Slider.Maximum` and `Slider.Minimum` but is there a way to override this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way! Go to the following thread:

[MSDN Accessibility Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/623ad3b0-afa5-4e27-8905-b27b44e84f26)